# How to grab json data and store in a database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get data from a json and i want to save it in a database.
I got errors, kindly put me through. Below is me code.

```
<?php

//My connection was ok

//read the json file contents
$url = ('http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/61/players/');
$jsondata = file_get_contents($url);

//convert json object to php associative array
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
//print_r($data);

//get the employee details
foreach ($data['_links']['players'] as $myp) {
    $name = $myp['name'];
    $posi = $myp['position'];
    $nation = $myp['nationality'];
    $market = $myp['marketValue'];
}

//    //insert into mysql table
mysql_select_db($db, $conn); //database and connection 

$date = date('Y-m-d H:m:s'); //date stamp formatting
//sql query that insert the user info into the database
$sql = "INSERT INTO player ( Name, Position, Nationality, Market, Created)       
        VALUES( ?,?,?,?,?)";
// bind variables to insert query params
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, 'sss', $name, $posi, $nation, $market, $date);
//if the connection is sucessful, display regards message
if (mysql_query($sql, $conn)) {
    echo "Thank you <br/>";
} else {   //if the connection is not established
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($conn); //close of process or connection
?>
```

I have tried to first print the values/datas that I want so that am sure the **foreach** loop is working but I also got errors:

Notice: Undefined index: players in C:\xampp\htdocs\lab4\apitest.php on line 22

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\lab4\apitest.php on line 22

Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lab4\apitest.php on line 31

Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lab4\apitest.php on line 38

Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lab4\apitest.php on line 40
Error:

Here is my json:

```
{

    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/61/players"
        },
        "team": {
            "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/61"
        }
    },
    "count": 25,
    "players": [
        {
            "name": "Marcos Alonso",
            "position": "Left-Back",
            "jerseyNumber": 3,
            "dateOfBirth": "1990-12-28",
            "nationality": "Spain",
            "contractUntil": "2021-06-30",
            "marketValue": "9,000,000 €"
        },
        {
            "name": "Marco van Ginkel",
            "position": "Central Midfield",
            "jerseyNumber": null,
            "dateOfBirth": "1992-12-01",
            "nationality": "Netherlands",
            "contractUntil": "2018-06-30",
            "marketValue": "7,000,000 €"
        },
```

Kindly help me on how to read the wanted data and store in a database successfully.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a problem with your data access method. You write:

```
foreach ($data['_links']['players'] as $myp) {
```

you must change into this to get the right structure:

```
foreach ($data['players'] as $myp) {
```

Because **players** key is not child of **_links**.

And second problem is if you want to insert all players into database. You must move and insert and execute statement into foreach loop.

Hope this help you!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
foreach ($data['players'] as $myp) {
    $name = $myp['name'];
    $posi = $myp['position'];
    $nation = $myp['nationality'];
    $market = $myp['marketValue'];
}
```